# Is the Perl Parser safe to parse arbitrary code?

Tags: security, parsing, perl

I've had a hard time finding an authoritative answer to this. Is the Perl 5 Parser safe to parse arbitrary code? Ignoring the implications of running or executing the code, is the parser itself consider safe?

Would a vulnerability in the parser that allows arbitrary code execution be consider a security vulnerability, or a bug?

It seems that there are tickets that are rejected from the security lists and pushed to general on parser-specific bugs,

For example, [a "Keeper of the Pumpkin" Tony Cook says,](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=126443#txn-1372621)

> I think in general we consider such issues as not a security concern, after all, if an attacker can provide code to the parser, you're already vulnerable.

Specifically I'm trying to clarify these two threat models,

- Safe assumes that Perl was able to generate a blacklist/whitelist opcode-tree correctly
- Perl (p5p) assumes that all parsing is done with the full capabilities of arbitrary code execution and that if malicious code was provided you're *"already vulnerable"*

---

**Questions**

> Would be interesting to know why you ask. Info on that could get you better answers.

If the perl parser is unable to parse code safely then I believe nothing can secure arbitrary Perl. So the whole purpose of Safe.pm and OpCode.pm is moot because you can't safely generate an opcode tree to prune (blacklist opcodes). If so, that's not clear anywhere in the docs, and keeping that kind of thing secretive is a very poor idea. It would be precarious to namedrop and open up software to exploitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not feed untrusted code to `perl`. The [Perl security model](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html) is centred about data (e.g. through the taint flag), and not about providing a sandbox for code. I.e. you should be able to write secure programs, but not necessarily be able to run arbitrary programs securely. So if someone is able to execute code, you should assume they are indeed able to execute any code.

One aspect of this is Perl's multi-phase execution model. BEGIN blocks are executed as soon as they are parsed. This is necessary in order to parse subsequent code correctly. The `use` statements are also BEGIN blocks. So because code must be executed during parsing, it is incorrect to think that first the Perl code is parsed and then it is executed. Consider this example:

```
say 4;
BEGIN {
  say 2;
  BEGIN { say 1 }
  say 3;
}
say 5;
```

Each BEGIN block is executed as soon as parsing it has completed, resulting in the numbered execution order. Importantly, some code is executed before parsing the whole document has completed.

While parsing, the perl compiler creates an optree. This optree is both an abstract syntax tree for the parser, and the opcodes for the Perl interpreter.

Perl does offer the ability to filter ops through the `Opcode` module, which should only be used through the frontends `ops` or `Safe`. These can set up a mask which controls which opcodes can be created while the mask is in effect. Thus, if we disallow loop opcodes but a loop is parsed, the parsing will fail at that point. Importantly the mask does not filter opcodes between compilation and execution (those two are not clearly delineated phases!). Instead, it prevents those opcodes from ever existing.

There are a number of huge caveats with this.

- Parsing is error prone. If there is a vulnerability in the parsing code, that could be exploited by specially crafted input.
- The `Safe` module tries to whitelist or blacklist allowed opcodes. However, it is not necessarily clear that a certain set of allowed opcodes is safe. Perl was not designed with sandboxing in mind.

  Also, a lot of functionality is not provided by opcodes but by subroutines, which may have been compiled before the opcode mask was in place. Their functionality or vulnerabilities in their implementation could be used to escape a sandbox. In particular, I expect that many XS modules could be used here because they often expose pointers to Perl code.

If you must execute untrusted Perl code, it may be best to use operating-system level security features, possibly in addition to the Perl security features. Linux containerization tech comes to mind. If you perform any parsing + execution in a sandboxed process, this would probably be sufficiently secure for untrusted code – iff the sandbox is configured properly. E.g. a seccomp rulechain can be built to allow/deny certain syscalls. Cgroups can set fine-grained resource limits.

Comment: When you say, "Parsing is error prone. If there is a vulnerability in the parsing code, that could be exploited by specially crafted input." You use the term *"vulnerability"* could you explain how the perl team would interpret that -- would such a problem be a "bug" or a "security" issue? Which list would it be sent too, and how would the perl threat model consider that? Would a cve go out? That's what I was really looking for specifically.

Comment: I can't tell you what p5p would do. I would consider parser exploits to be severe, security-sensitive, and CVE-worthy bugs, but not catastrophic security issues. For most applications, if you can pass arbitrary code to perl you can already run arbitrary code and don't need such exploits. Counter-examples are setuid scripts that eval user input (oh god why??). But because of the multi-phase execution model, those must already implement some sandbox before starting to parse the untrusted code, and a parser vulnerability would be contained. I don't consider `Safe` to be a sufficient sandbox here.

Comment: Right but the point is threat-model alignment. If a product is built properly with Safe.pm, lacking OS-level isolation, would 100% of the security-related issues be CVE-worthy. It seems to me from tcook's statement that there is a threat modeling problem between p5p and users of Safe. Safe assumes that Perl was able to generate a blacklist/whitelist opcode-tree correctly, and Perl assumes that all parsing is done with the full capabilities of arbitrary code execution.

Answer (score 4):

> Is the Perl 5 Parser safe to parse arbitrary code?

No.

```
BEGIN { print "This runs at parse time.\n" }
```

There is no way to disable this behavior, either, as code which runs at parse time may take actions which are required to parse the following code, like installing source filters or adding keywords.

Comment: But anything in that `BEGIN` block happens *after* the parsing for that `BEGIN` block. For instance, you can't work around `Opcode.pm` with a `BEGIN` block, right? Is the parsing of that BEGIN block secure though, meaning the construction of the perl optree from arbitrary source itself.

Comment: @EvanCarroll BEGIN blocks are executed during parsing of the surrounding code. And BEGIN blocks can be nested. Executing BEGIN blocks ASAP is necessary in order to parse the following code correctly. So you can't think about perl's parser as separate from perl's interpreter – the two are inseparably linked. Parsing Perl means executing Perl. Therefore, `perl -c` is a kind of lie, as it executes BEGIN blocks.

Comment: I'm confused, if they're inseparably linked then how does OpCode.pm work in such a way that I can't think of it being a separate process from the parsing of `BEGIN {}`

Comment: @EvanCarroll While parsing and execution is intermingled, the different phases are still ordered. You can apply restrictions _before parsing_ certain code. The Opcode restrictions (internally, the `PL_op_mask` array) are checked as soon as an OP is created, i.e. during parsing and before it can be executed. See the `CHECKOP` macro in op.c of the perl interpreter.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how you're using "different" and "intermingled": if you have the opcodes the parsing is complete. If the parser is insecure, you can generate whatever opcodes you want assuming you find a bug -- and the Perl community wouldn't consider it a "security vulnerability" because parsing arbitrary code is insecure. I'm unclear about the distinction between those two words, or how `BEFORE` illustrates a problem for *parsing* (subject of the question) and not *execution*?